# How to put live video from web camera to Django website?

Tags: python, django

I have developed a face recognition software.It detects and identify human faces infront of the connected web camera.Now I need to deploy it in a website.so that,Anyone with a computer should be able to access this service through this website and should be able to perform face detection and identification using the camera in his premises.
Is it possible to integrate python application with website?
Is Django framework is suitable for my work?
Can anybody recommed any tutorials in this direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got absolutely nothing to do with Django. Django is running in your server, whereas you need to capture image at your client. Therefore it has to do about your *front-end* and not your *back-end*.

Traditionally this has been a feature not at all possible. A web browser could not access the client's peripherals and end of story. Flash, activex etc have been workarounds for this.

[HTML5 now allows](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/) it. Read more on [MDN about `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

Unfortunately this is still fresh at the time of writing and is only supported by [some browser versions: read more on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia).

You could use some js library for feature detection such as [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).